# table have problems

Tags: php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)


{

die('Could Not Connect: '. mysql_error());

}
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing

$bilboard_list = "";
$bilboard_list0 = "";
$bilboard_list1 = "";
$bilboard_list2 = "";
$bilboard_list3 = "";
$bilboard_list4 = "";
$bilboard_list5 = "";
$bilboard_list6 = "";
$bilboard_list7 = "";
$bilboard_list8 = "";
$bilboard_list9 = "";
$bilboard_list10 = "";
$bilboard_list11 = "";
$bilboard_list12 = "";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maklumat_peribadi ORDER BY id");

$bilboardCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount

if ($bilboardCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){


$id = $row["id"];
$nama_penuh = $row["nama_penuh"];
$no_ic = $row["no_ic"];
$alamat_ttp = $row["alamat_ttp"];
$no_rumah = $row["no_rumah"];
$no_bimbit = $row["no_bimbit"];
$jantina = $row["jantina"];
$tmpt_lhir = $row["tmpt_lhir"];
$email = $row["email"];
$agama = $row["agama"];
$bangsa = $row["bangsa"];
$negara = $row["negara"];
$nama_penjaga = $row["nama_penjaga"];
$nama_ibu = $row["nama_ibu"];



//for show

$bilboard_list .= "$No<br>";
$bilboard_list0 .= "$Nama<br>";
$bilboard_list1 .= "$No Kad Pengenalan<br>";
$bilboard_list2 .= "$Alamat<br>";
$bilboard_list3 .= "$No Telefon Rumah<br>";
$bilboard_list4 .= "$No Telefon Bimbit<br>";
$bilboard_list5 .= "$Jantina<br>";
$bilboard_list6 .= "$Tempat Lahir<br>";
$bilboard_list7 .= "$Email<br>";
$bilboard_list8 .= "$Agama<br>";
$bilboard_list9 .= "$Bangsa<br>";
$bilboard_list10 .= "$Warganegara<br>";
$bilboard_list11.= "$Nama Penjaga/Bapa<br>";
$bilboard_list12 .= "$Nama Ibu<br>";

}
}
 ?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="2col_leftNav.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

 <body>
<div id="masthead">
  <h1 id="siteName">Admin Site</h1>
  <div id="globalNav"> <a href="adminpage.php"> Halaman Utama</a> |   <a href="test.php">Maklumat Peribadi Pelajar | <a href="adminpage.php">Senarai Pelajar Mengikut Kursus  |  <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
</div>
<table width="1000px" border="1" align="center">

      <tr>

        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>NO<strong></span></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>NAMA</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>NO KAD PENGENALAN</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>ALAMAT</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>NO TELEFON RUMAH</strong></td>\
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>NO TELEFON BIMBIT</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>JANTINA</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>TEMPAT LAHIR</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>EMAIL</strong></td>\
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>AGAMA</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>BANGSA</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>WARGANEGARA</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>NAMA PENJAGA/BAPA</strong></td>
        <td width="auto"><span class="style1"><strong>NAMA IBU</strong></td>



      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list0; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list3 ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list4; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list5; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list6; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list7; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list8; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list9; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list10; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list11; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bilboard_list12; ?></td>



      </tr>

</table>

<body>

</html>
`
```

I have this code with me. 
But whenever I try to run this code it will show this:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\ftn_eg\table.php on line 32

Can anybody can help me?

Comment: `mysql_` function are unsafe and deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead. I recommend PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Your query has failed. You need to check for failure with something like `if (!$sql) echo mysql_error();`

Comment: As a side note, you should change `$bilboard_list`, `$bilboard_list0` ... `$bilboard_list12` into an array.

Answer (score 1):

In your code missing select database functions

you should use `mysql_select_db('your_db_name');` before running `mysql_query` function

Comment: Or use $con as parameter in query execute

Comment: And you can get what the error using `mysql_error` function use it with `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maklumat_peribadi ORDER BY id")or die(mysql_error());` I think in this case it will return "No database selected" as error.

Comment: I'm sayed using `$con` as parameter in query execute like `mysql_query('SQL QUERY', $con)`

Answer (score 0):

Your query

```
SELECT * FROM maklumat_peribadi ORDER BY id
```

is returning false. Check your database

Answer (score 0):

Lets, first start off by saying, don't use mysql_* functions. This time has passed, and you should now use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

With that said, your not selecting a database. Where is the MySQL supposed to pull from?

`mysql_select_db('DATABASE_NAME');`

Next, there are going to be a lot of foreseeable syntax errors when trying to print this information.
`$bilboard_list3 .= "$No Telefon Rumah<br>";` which is supposed to be a variable from what I can read, needs to be something like `$bilboard_list3 .= "$No_Telefon_Rumah<br>";`

Lastly, most of these variables can be reduced down to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a schema using `mysql_select_db`. You only connect to a database system, not to a specific database.

It is good practice that you are checking the results with `if ($bilboardCount > 0) {`, but your output is not looking if there were results to show. You might get error messages on your page.

Using `PDO` will make some things a lot easier and safer for you. And even if the data comes from the database, you should escape it using `htmlspecialchars` when you show it on the page.

A good thing for improvement would be to create an object for $bilboard_list :)

Keep it up! :)